# How do I position a window in WPF in an exact location?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I'm trying to display a window that aligns with an existing component. In this example I want to align it to a button. When i click the button I would like the window to position itself so that it's bottom is just above the button, and it's width is the same as the button. The left of the window should be the same as the left of the button.

To achieve this I use the following xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowPositioningTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowPositioningTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Name="MyButton" Content="Click me to see window!" Width="300" Height="50" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

The onclick function looks like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new Window();

        var myButtonLocation = MyButton.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

        window.Width = MyButton.ActualWidth;
        window.Height = 300;
        window.Left = myButtonLocation.X;
        window.Top = myButtonLocation.Y - window.Height;

        window.Show();
    }
```

When I click the button a window is displayed like in the picture below.

[image]

My question is: why is the window not as wide as the button and why is it not in the right position? It's almost as if there's an invisible frame around the window.

Comment: Seems like the drop shadow is part of the window

Comment: Yep! So it seems. Question is if I could somehow learn the width of that so I can adjust the width and left pos of the window accordingly. The window width should be the same as the button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = new Window();

    var myButtonLocation = MyButton.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

    window.Width = MyButton.ActualWidth + 16;
    window.Height = 300;
    window.Left = myButtonLocation.X - 8;
    window.Top = myButtonLocation.Y - window.Height;

    window.Show();
}
```

It happens beacuse of window border. As you know, window is a composite element. I think when you set Width, you set a width of the working space, not the width of the whole window.

Comment: I guess this wouild work, but I was hoping for something more elegant. Where do you get 8 from? Just trial and error? Wouild this work for all Operative systems?

Comment: @Fred yeah, I just try to guess this number. I think it is the same for windows 8 and windows 10, but it may be different for win7, vista, and XP. I am not sure.